# Understanding typeid.name() output for Maps and Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, maps, typeid

Can someone help to better understand the output of `typeid.name()` on Maps and Vectors? Please find my program and its output below.

For example: output  for  `std::map<int,int>` comes out to `TYPE is: [St3mapIiiSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiiEEE]` where I am able to decipher a little bit i.e. *map* for `std::map` ofcourse, *Iii* for the `int,int` but what does the rest of the characters mean?

**Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std ;

template <class A>
void showtype (A x)
{
        cout<<"TYPE is: ["<<typeid(x).name()<<"]\n" ;
}

int main()
{
        std::map<int,int> iM ;                  showtype(iM) ;
        std::map<int,std::string> isM ;         showtype(isM) ;
        std::map<std::string,std::string> ssM ; showtype(ssM) ;
        std::vector<std::string> sV ;           showtype(sV) ;
        std::vector<int> iV ;                   showtype(iV) ;
        return 0 ;
}
```

**Output:**

```
%_Host@User> ./typeid.name
TYPE is: [St3mapIiiSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiiEEE]
TYPE is: [St3mapIiSsSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiSsEEE]
TYPE is: [St3mapISsSsSt4lessISsESaISt4pairIKSsSsEEE]
TYPE is: [St6vectorISsSaISsEE]
TYPE is: [St6vectorIiSaIiEE]
%_Host@User>
```

Comment: Try-at-home command: `c++filt <<< "_ZSt3mapIiiSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKiiEEE"`

Comment: Thanks Kerrek. I am able to see the expansion of the rest of the characters.

Comment: What is the '_Z' for? is it some kind of flag? without it nothing happens.

Comment: See my answer and the link therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your platform uses the Itanium ABI, and in particular that ABI's [name mangling scheme](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling). The detailed rules are in the linked specification.

Your library implementation chooses to return the (significant part of the) name thus mangled from `std::type_info::name`. This is a fortunate coincidence not required by the Standard (in fact, the Standard has no concept of linking and name mangling).

GCC's ABI library contains a function to demangle names in [`abi::__cxa_demangle`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) (but don't use it on untrusted input, since it is full of vulnerabilities!). There's also a free-standing command line tool to do demangling on Linux, `c++filt`, and the Linux binutils (`nm`, `objdump`, `readelf`) can demangle names, too. (For the same reason, don't run those on untrusted input.)

Comment: I am checking the provided link. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on the "untrusted input"? I am really new to this mangling thingy.

Comment: @UselessPerson: It's just that the algorithms are not implemented correctly by those libraries, so I can create a mangled name that takes over your computer and spawns a root shell etc. It's OK to use the algorithms on names *generated by your compiler*, though.